# What does "passing smokes stage" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, phrase-usage, time

> The goddess Dhūmavatī is described as Vivarnā, Chañchalā and Rustā
> with her rough behaviour and unclean robes. Her appearance is like a
> widow sitting on a chariot carried by a crow. This goddess represents
> the ugly side of creation which is as true as its brighter side.
> Besides it also represents a passing smokes stage intermediate between
> ignorance and knowledge.

-- from the Book: Dasa Mahavidya & Tantra Sastra

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a choice of words that has meaning to others. A Google search for those words, inside quote marks to search as a phrase, shows only this passage and no other results. The meaning is clear enough from context: an "intermediate" or "in between" stage.

Comment: I think this is just a non-idiomatic expression written by a non-native speaker of English. It may be a literal translation of an expression in Hindi, or Sanskrit. I don't think any answer is possible.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, Dhūmavatī means "The smoky one" or "She that abides in smoke"